# выборка, исключая пустые записи

Tags: php, mysql

в таблице есть поле `name`,которое задано null=no, default=no
и нужно выбрать значения которые не пустые.
Пробовал

```
$empty = "";
"SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` IS NOT ".$empty.""

$empty = '%[^ ]%';
"SELECT name` FROM `"categories` WHERE `name` LIKE ".$empty."";
```

Оба раза дают пустой ответ. Я понимаю, что поле в таблице по дефолту не null а пустое, то бишь пустая строка, но где ошибка

Comment: может быть $empty = ''; -- две одинарных кавычки  или `<>`  вместо `is not`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас $empty это *ничего*. при сборке вашего запроса получается `select .... name is not`, все, после `not` у вас ничего не идет. А должна быть пустая строка, т.е. $empty должно быть равно `''` т.е. двум апострофам. `$empty="''"`.

В случае с like ваш запрос выглядит как `SELECT name FROM categories WHERE name LIKE %[^ ]%`. Опять же, строка для SQL не заключена в апострофы - что вызывает ошибку.

Ну либо пусть `$empty` остается пустым, а sql собирайте с апострофами:

```
"SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` <> '".$empty."'"
```

А вообще, гораздо лучше не подставлять переменную в сам текст запроса, а использовать привязываемые параметры. [Например для mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 2):

Если надо выбрать записи, в которых поле не равно пустой строке, то так и надо писать

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` <> ''
```